# Displaying records for two weeks only! from creation

Tags: c#, linq

The problem I am having is displaying records from a database which are no more than 14 days old. The idea is that someone would create an advert and it would be displayed for two weeks only.

I am New to LinQ and finding the syntax for such a query difficult to comprehend.

The following query has been created to display all the adverts shown below.

```
var Adverts = from m in db. Adverts
 select m;
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve.

```
var Adverts = from m in db. Adverts
where m.date  == DateTime.Now 

---- Unsure of how to input a date range ------

 select m;
```

Any advice welocme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var twoWeeksAgo = now.AddDays(-14);
var adverts = 
    from advert in db. Adverts
    where advert.date >= twoWeeksAgo && advert.date <= now
    select advert;
```

Answer (score 1):

One line lambda should get you:

```
var adverts = db.Adverts.Where(x => x.date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14) && x.date <= DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` class implements `IComparable`. Thus, you can do this.

```
var results = from ad in Adverts
              where ad.date <= DateTime.Now &&
                    ad.date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14) 
              select ad;
```